# Containers not running in detached mode

Tags: docker, devops, docker-run

Today I tried to run my containers in detached mode and I faced some issue.

When I ran the command **docker container run -d nginx**, the image of nginx got pulled and the output of the container was not shown as it was in detached mode.

Then I ran the command **docker container ls** which we all know shows only running containers and it showed my nginx container running.
[image: Image for nginx image]

Then I tried the same thing with the ubuntu image i.e.
**docker container run -d ubuntu** but when I ran **docker container ls** command my ubuntu image was not running, only the nginx container was running.

[image: Image for ubuntu image]

Why is it so?

Answer (score 8):

You don't see a running container with the `ubuntu` image, because the container stops immediately after being started. while the `nginx` image starts an nginx server that keeps the container running, the `ubuntu` image executes a `sh -c "bash"` on start - bash is not a process that keeps on running after execution. You will be able to see your stopped `ubuntu` container with the `docker ps -a`

If you want to keep the `ubuntu` container running, you need to pass it a command that starts a process that keeps on running, e.g. `docker run -d ubuntu tail -f /dev/null`

Comment: great answer :)